# Using iframe with a command button

Tags: html

I have a page with an iframe that doesn't refresh properly.  I've been trying some of the suggestions found here:

[How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

On the left of my page I have collapsing folders and hyperlinks within the folders.  When a link is clicked the iframe changes to the hyperlink's page.

The problem is that my iframe does not refresh under specific circumstances.

Some of the links open an FAQ that is pre-filtered by the link.  For example, if this link is clicked FAQs related to approve, approver, or approvals are found:

```
<li class=""><a href="http://vuwppqws01.americas.sqpd.local/Finance/Training/FAQs.htm#0,approv" target="imgbox">FAQ: Approval </a> </li>
```

Unfortunately, on the left side of the page, after clicking an FAQ link and then clicking a different FAQ link it does not refresh the iframe.  I am forced to click a different link (like one that opens a pdf in the iframe) and then click one of the FAQ links for the list to refresh.

So I tried using a command button:

```
<form action="http://vuwppqws01.americas.sqpd.local/Finance/Training/FAQs.htm#0,approv" target="imgbox">
    <li class=""><input type="submit" value="FAQ-Approvers" /></li></form>
```

It seems close to working because it does refresh but it ignores the part of the string that finds the FAQs that I'm looking for.  It ignores the #,0,approv at the end of the url.

Is there a way to force the form command button to use the entire url and included the search parameters?  For example, it uses this:

http://vuwppqws01.americas.sqpd.local/Finance/Training/FAQs.htm

but it ignores this:

http://vuwppqws01.americas.sqpd.local/Finance/Training/FAQs.htm#0,approv

Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited the html in my question because it apparently limits the number of links.

Comment: When including code examples in your question, make sure that the code is formatted as code.  That will make it easier to review your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help